# Docker can't find OpenJDK

Tags: docker, java-8, java

I am experimenting with Docker for the first time, and am trying to get a Spring Boot web app to run inside a Docker container. I am building the app (which packages up into a self-contained jar) and *then* adding it to the Docker image (which is what I want).

I am following the instructions from the [OpenJDK Docker base image](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk/) here. You can find my [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) at this [Bootup repo on GitHub](https://github.com/hotmeatballsoup/bootup), whose README has all the instructions to reproduce what I'm seeing. But basically:

- I build the web app into a jar
- Run `docker build -t bootup .` which succeeds
- Run `docker run -it --rm --name bootup bootup` which gives me the error below and then exits

The error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: /bin/sh: [java,: not found
```

According to the [Google Gods](https://github.com/dockerfile/java/issues/27), this *used* to be a problem with the Oracle JDK images, but should *not* be happening with OpenJDK images.

Looking at my Dockerfile (which is also up in that GitHub repo), can anyone spot where I'm going awry:

```
FROM openjdk:8
RUN mkdir /opt/bootup
ADD build/libs/bootup.jar /opt/bootup
WORKDIR /opt/bootup
ENTRYPOINT ['java', '-jar', 'bootup.jar']
CMD ['']
```

Thanks in advance!

---

**Update**:

Output of `docker ps`:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED
16bde964ff6b        bootup              "/bin/sh -c 'java -ja"   2 days ago

STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
Up 14 seconds       0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   bootup
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had it working fine using this dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8

RUN mkdir /opt/bootup

ADD build/libs/bootup.jar /opt/bootup
WORKDIR /opt/bootup
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT java -jar bootup.jar
```

It runs just fine with this commad:

```
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 --name bootup bootup
```

I am no java developer and I don't know why it ignores your configuration that requires it to start on port 9200, since your app starts on port 8080, but from a docker point of view everything is working with my config and I can connect to the app from my browser on localhost:8080

Here the screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Also, since you posted your github repo I suggest you to modify the readme so that users can start gradle from docker without the need of a java environment in the host machine running this one time command:

```
docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp openjdk:8 /usr/src/myapp/gradlew clean build
```

Comment: Thanks @TopperH (+1) - your Dockerfile change got me about 90% of the way there! Now, when I run `docker run -it --rm --name bootup bootup`, the Docker container *appears* to start up and run (I can see it by running `docker ps`), but **three (3)** undesirable things are happening. (1) the terminal window that I run `docker run -it --rm --name bootup bootup` in is printing out all the STDOUT logging, whereas my app is configured to send log messages to `/var/log/bootup/bootup*.log`. **I don't want STDOUT going to the host's terminal...any way to fix?**

Comment: (2) Along the same lines, the `docker run -it --rm --name bootup bootup` command never returns control to the command-line/terminal/prompt. Its almost as if the app is running right on my host machine, and not on Docker at all. **Any way to run it and get my command-line back?**

Comment: (3) **Most importantly**, I think I need to do some port forwarding (or something), because when I do `docker run -it --rm --name bootup bootup` and then point my browser to `http://localhost:9200` I'm not getting anything. **Any ideas what the fix is there?** Thanks again!

Comment: Also, per the whole "build from inside the image/container so the user doesn't need Java on the host machine"-thing, I appreciate the concept and need to stew on it for a while. But this is ultimately a JVM app that will be maintained by JVM devs, and so I'm not too worried about my audience having their host machine set up correctly. But again, I will mull it over. In the meantime, I still have those 3 issues above to tackle! Thanks again for your help with this, I think I'm almost there!

Comment: Can you docker `run -it -d --rm --name bootup bootup` and then `docker exec -it bootup /bin/bash`

Comment: Thanks @ManoMarks (+1) but for that first command, Docker says "*Conflicting options: --rm and -d*"...any ideas?

Comment: try just `docker run -it -d --name bootup bootup`

Comment: Thanks again @ManoMarks (+1) - that worked, and so did that second one (`docker exec -it bootup /bin/bash`), however the 2nd one gave no console output (so, no success messages, but no errors either). what was that testing for and what are your thoughts here?!

Comment: Oh sorry I thought you just needed access to the logs. Looks like what you needed was to make the logs not go to the host's terminal, which the first command, running as a daemon, accomplished. For the third problem, you need to expose a port using ` -p 9200:9200 ` when you run. Assuming you're using Docker for Mac or Docker for Windows that should give you access to localhost:9200.

Comment: Ahh, gotchya @ManoMarks, thanks again (and +1). So I re-ran the `docker run` command with your suggestion (so, `docker run -it -p 9200:9200 -d --name bootup bootup`) and still can't see anything when I point my browser to `http://localhost:9200`. And yes, I'm on Mac using Docker for Mac. Any ideas? I don't have any firewalls enabled, etc. (that I know of).

Comment: @smeeb Can you post the output of docker ps?

Comment: @smeeb my new config works now, but your config to have the app on port 9200 is ignored in favour of 8080. I am no java dev, so I have no idea of what is wrong. The docker side works perfectly now

Comment: @TopperH (+1 for both) - I have updated my answer with the output of `docker ps`. What is the purpose of exposing port 8089 inside `Dockerfile` but then passing in `-p 8080:8080` in the run command? It seems like 8089 is a defunct port?

Comment: Ops, that was an error, just removed the expose line

Comment: @smeeb, the docker ps you posted wasn't using the command line from my answer

Comment: @TopperH please see my updated `docker ps` output (above). I stopped/removed the other container and then restarted with your `-p 8080:8080` flag. **This is still not working.** Also, I don't see how it ever could, because the web app thats running inside of it *only* starts up on port 9200 (see for yourself just by running `./gradlew clean build && java -jar build/libs/bootup.jar`). If it is working, you should see a message that says "*Well hello there, from Dockerland!*" when you go to `localhost:9200`. Thoughts? Thanks again!

Comment: I think this is turning into a different port forwarding problem. I'm awarding you the green check and will post another question about this port issue. Thank you for helping me solve the original problem, which was an issue with running a JVM process from inside of Docker!

Comment: @smeeb, take a look at the screenshot I just added. Your app works just fine, but on port 8080, not 9200.